# Setting a tail indent for a label in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am a beginner in iOS and am trying to make a number pad. The problem I am having is that, the text(number display) is too close to the border. As you can see in the picture below.

[image: original numpad]

I first tried to use attributedString instead of plain text in the label. But setting it to 1 gives me this. Even setting it to 0.0000000001 does not differ any.

[image: bad numpad1]
[image: bad numpad2]

This is my configuration

[image: setting]

Since this method does not seem to work, I then tried to use paragraph style. Here is my code

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.tailIndent = -0.1
let attributes = [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle]
```

Then I realized `myLabel.attributedText` is a `NSAttributedString`, not `NSMutableAttributableString`, which means it does not have a `addAttribute` method. I have not found any way to make `myLabel.attributedText` a `NSMutableAttributableString`. So that does not work for me.

### Question

My question is, how can I give a proper tail indent to my text in the label?

### Update

I tried this and it does not work.

```
@IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel! 
    didSet {
        let myString = display.attributedText!.string
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.tailIndent = -0.0000000001
        let attributes = [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle]
        let myMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: myString, attributes: attributes)

        display.attributedText = myMutableAttributedString
    }
}
```

gives me this
[image: new try]

Comment: You can create and assign an instance of `NSMutableAttributedString` to the `attributedText` property

Comment: You can add another view that only has the border and add the label with the smaller frame on top of it.

Comment: How do you add a label on top of another?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `NSMutableAttributedString` in your `attributedText` property because it is a subclass of `NSAttributedString`:

```
let myString = "0.01"
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.tailIndent = -0.1
let attributes = [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle]

let myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(
                         string: myString,
                         attributes: attributes)
```

Then in `myLabel`:

```
myLabel.attributedText = myMutableString
```

Comment: It does not work quiet right. The text is pushed all the way to the left in the label even I set tailindent to -0.001. In fact, setting it to -0.1 or -0.001 does not differ between each other. Any ideas?

Comment: Set the tailIndent to a larger number like -10 and set textAlignment to the right:

myLabel.textAlignment = .right

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Seems like a negative `tailIndent` value is sadly only respected if the text is long enough to cause a line break. In this case all lines are indented as intended. If the text length roughly fills the label's width a negative `tailIndent` value is does not cause a line break as I had hoped in my case.